explicit template function instantiation - Howto find the codepoints where it's been used?
I like to know how I can find the codepoints where an explicit instantiated template function is been used.
template <typename T> RNNullableTyped<T> Get(const json::json &json);
template <> RNNullableTyped<int         > Get(const json::json &json);
template <> RNNullableTyped<double      > Get(const json::json &json);
template <> RNNullableTyped<std::string > Get(const json::json &json);
template <> RNNullableTyped<std::wstring> Get(const json::json &json);


std::string AsString(const json::json &elem)
{
  return Get< std::string >(elem).Get();
}

Now I like to find codepoints like the above, but I cannot easily search for it. If I comment it out, I just get an unresolved external linker error. Annotate it as deprecated seems not to be supported for template functions.
So, to solve that issue a colleague of mine is going to replace those temple function with explicit once like GetInt, GetDouble, GetStdString, GetStdWstring ... and so forth, which I do not like very much....
What I hope for is that someone can show me a way how to find the points in code where a explicit instantiated template function is been used.
I should add, that we use the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler.
Regards,
Ronald.

"Annotate it as been deprecated seems not to be supported for template functions." - What do you mean? Seems to work ok https://wandbox.org/permlink/BLctd9nnGiNL8YOI (also in msvc with high enough warning levels https://godbolt.org/z/3GKxosx9f)

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica It looks like it doesn't work in MSVC. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/xrxjfPcKj

@sklott - It does. I posted two links, and compiler options to make it work in the second.

I wasn't aware that MS now fully supported [[deprecated]], they seemed had their own __declspec(deprecated). Always calls for a macro use.

There is no difference between the use of an explicit instantiation or implicit instantiation. For one, an explicit instantiation itself does/is the instantiation.

In the OP, the lines that begin with template <>  are declarations of function template specializations. An explicit instantiation begins with begins with template, alone, and does use empty angle brackets: <>.

Annotate with [[deprecated]], and add /we4996 or /w14996 or /W4 to your compiler flags.

I mistyped my comment above. It should say: An explicit instantiation begins with begins with template, alone, and does NOT use empty angle brackets: <>.

Thank you all. The code is part of a legacy codebase developed since >28year. So, yes, marking the function as deprecated works, just the error C4996 wasn't enabled. Thanks again for the quick help!

First of all, these are explicit specialization declarations, not explicit instantiation definitions. Explicit specialization declarations begin with template<>, while explicit instantiation declarations begin with template or extern template, neither followed by <.
For the explicit specialization declarations there must be corresponding explicit specialization definitions somewhere in a source file.
You can find all uses of the specialization either via tools of your IDE (ideally it should be able to show you all references to a specific specialization of the function template.)
Alternatively you can mark the explicit specializations with [[deprecated]] which should cause the compiler to emit a warning when they are referred to:
template <> [[deprecated]] RNNullableTyped<int         > Get(const json::json &json);

Alternatively you can mark the explicit specialization declaration as inline in the header file, but then comment out the explicit specialization definition in the source file. Then, hopefully, the compiler should warn when the explicit specialization is odr-used because its definition is not available although it is marked inline:
template <> inline RNNullableTyped<int         > Get(const json::json &json);

Another possibility would be to define the explicit specilizations as deleted:
template <> RNNullableTyped<int         > Get(const json::json &json) = delete;

Then the compiler will fail to compile any use of the specialization.

While the comments on my initial question also help me to spot the issue, i mark this as the accepted answer as it's the only i can mark... ;) Thank you.
